# Facing "TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()" while executing the below script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iam trying to check whether the product is 12 or not by using assert equal function.Please check the below script i have tried:

```
def test_search(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='search']").send_keys("Bed & Bath")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='search_mini_form']/div[1]/button").click()
    lis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name'] / a")
    self.assertEqual(12,len(lis))
```

Comment: Are you sure "//h2[@class='product-name'] / a" is valid xpath for your case? Please check manually with chrome console

Comment: Yes ..it's valid xpath only

Comment: What do you see on chrome console? How many elements it catches?

Comment: Actually this xpath "//h2[@class='product-name'] / a"
 explains the ancor tag "a" catches 12 products under site "http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/" .. Iam  looking forward to check whether the 12 products is present or not...

Answer (score 23):

Replace this :

```
lis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
```

To :

```
lis = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
```

Note that `find_elements` will return a **list** of **web element** where as `find_element` will only return one element if found.

Comment: When I tried with this xpath //h2[@class='product-name']/a , it showed me 9 elements at my end , please re-verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using driver.find_element_by_xpath rather than driver.find_elements_by_xpath.
You may also want to take the spaces out of

```
"//h2[@class='product-name'] / a"
```

I don't believe that's a valid xpath with spaces in there.

-- Edit -
That's a valid xpath however switching to find_elements_by_xpath worked for me -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path = driver_path)
driver.get('http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='search']").send_keys("Bed & Bath")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='search_mini_form']/div[1]/button").click()
lis = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")

print(len(lis))
```

Outputs a 9

Comment: But did you switch to find_elements_by_class_name?? That's what fixed it in my code - I edited it back into original answer.

Comment: still facing the same problem

Comment: I didn't tried by using the class name ..Because these xpath "//h2[@class='product-name'] / a"  manually written by me  .

Comment: Actually this xpath "//h2[@class='product-name'] / a" explains the ancor tag "a" catches 12 products under site "magento-demo.lexiconn.com/"; .. Iam looking forward to check whether the 12 products is present or not... – vignesh 4 mins ago   edit